# How to access hystrix dashboard?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I added following dependency to my spring boot aplication:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And marked configuration class with :

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableHystrix
```

I try to access `http://localhost:8080/hystrix`   (I also tried `http://localhost:8081/hystrix`)

and I see:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Nov 11 21:47:56 MSK 2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

During startup I see following messages:

```
2019-11-11 21:43:17.724  INFO 15912 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-11-11 21:43:22.581  INFO 15912 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-11 21:43:23.362  INFO 15912 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2019-11-11 21:43:23.507  INFO 15912 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
```

How to acces hystrix dashboard?

### P.S.

In debug I see that these methods are invoked but anyway I see error:

[image]

Also I see following response when I access URL: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream`

```
data: {"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"executeHttpCall","group":"MyAPIConnectorImpl","currentTime":1573503001364,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0,"rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,"rollingCountFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackEmit":0,"rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackMissing":0,"rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,"rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,"rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,"rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,"rollingCountShortCircuited":0,"rollingCountSuccess":0,"rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,"rollingCountTimeout":0,"currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"latencyExecute_mean":948,"latencyExecute":{"0":16,"25":18,"50":23,"75":1008,"90":3767,"95":3767,"99":3767,"99.5":3767,"100":3767},"latencyTotal_mean":950,"latencyTotal":{"0":16,"25":18,"50":24,"75":1019,"90":3767,"95":3767,"99":3767,"99.5":3767,"100":3767},"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"THREAD","propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,"reportingHosts":1,"threadPool":"MyAPIConnectorImpl"}

data: {"type":"HystrixThreadPool","name":"MyAPIConnectorImpl","currentTime":1573503001364,"currentActiveCount":0,"currentCompletedTaskCount":18,"currentCorePoolSize":10,"currentLargestPoolSize":10,"currentMaximumPoolSize":10,"currentPoolSize":10,"currentQueueSize":0,"currentTaskCount":18,"rollingCountThreadsExecuted":0,"rollingMaxActiveThreads":0,"rollingCountCommandRejections":0,"propertyValue_queueSizeRejectionThreshold":5,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"reportingHosts":1}

ping:
```

In debug log I see:

```
2019-11-11 23:41:28.436 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/hystrix/index", parameters={}
2019-11-11 23:41:28.447 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.HystrixDashboardController#monitor(String, Model, WebRequest)
2019-11-11 23:41:28.480 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [hystrix/index_ru_RU.ftlh]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.482 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [hystrix/index_ru.ftlh]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.482 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [hystrix/index.ftlh]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.485 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/signed-exchange;v=b3, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.485 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'hystrix/index', model {basePath=/hystrix/index, contextPath=}
2019-11-11 23:41:28.487 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [hystrix/index]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.491 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/hystrix/hystrix/index", parameters={}
2019-11-11 23:41:28.494 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.497 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-11-11 23:41:28.498 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2019-11-11 23:41:28.499 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-11-11 23:41:28.502 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2019-11-11 23:41:28.503 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2019-11-11 23:41:28.513 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error_ru_RU.ftlh]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.514 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error_ru.ftlh]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.514 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error.ftlh]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.515 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2019-11-11 23:41:28.519 DEBUG 6604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: I think the `artifactId` is `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard`

Comment: @clav Unfortunately result the same

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @JuanManuel unfortunately not

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem which got fixed using the below steps

1. Add the below annotations to the SpringBootApplication -- Where main method is present

   @EnableHystrixDashboard

   @EnableHystrix
2. In pom.xml

   org.springframework.cloud
           spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard

   org.springframework.boot
       spring-boot-starter-actuator

[image: pom.xml]

3. In application.properties

   management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
4. Hit the URL

   http://localhost:8081/hystrix

You should be able to see Hystrix Dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Hystrix searches for @HystrixCommand annotation in order to show data about the service you are trying to monitor, and it needs actuator endpoints.
You will need those three dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then try entering the url http://localhost:8080/hystrix. Once you see the hystrix dasboard ui, you should type in your stream's url which is http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream in your case. Finally, you will be able to view some data.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I am able to see some data from http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream but I expect to see beautiful UI

Comment: If you have those dependencies above in your project, then you could add this to your application properties to expose the dashboard: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream

Comment: In my yml I have following -  management:
  metrics:
    enable:
      all: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"

Comment: Do you have @EnableHystrix annotation on the application you want to monitor?

Comment: No - I don't have - let me check

Comment: Doesn't work - I have EnableCircuitBreaker
EnableHystrixDashboard
EnableHystrix annotations

Answer (score 1):

I did't know which spring-boot version you use, beacuse you should consider the compatibility between spring-boot and spring-cloud. If your spring-boot version is 2.2.2.RELEASE, try to change the hystrix-dashboard version to 2.2.0.RELEASE. If not, look up the release trains in https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Recommend to use dependency management tools to control the version.like this below:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide the good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is not enough. Please provide sample snippet, how you could change the version on `maven` and where it should be changed. This is too ambiguous.

Comment: @SachithDickwella Sorry for ambiguous. I just update my answer now